# Vertically positioning elements

Tags: html, css

This is more of a general purpose question in relation to vertically positioning an element; when it's one of few elements on the page.

HTML:

```
 <div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">
     <h1>text</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I need to do is just take the `h1` and move it so that its roughly 60% of the way down the page. Horizontal positioning is taken care of. I'm just curious as to what everyone's vertical positioning takes on this would be. Using `margin-top` or `padding-top` seems too simplistic an answer, and I'm wondering what kindve problems I could run into if that's the method I employ.

CSS:

```
 html,body {height:100%;width:100%}

 #outer {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
 }

 #inner {
  margin-top/padding-top: (value); 
  }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by `margin-top` or `padding-top` seeming too simplistic? If they work, what's wrong with that? Simple is better.

Comment: Do you want it to stay a certain distance from the top in pixels? If someone resizes their window to 200px tall, do you still want it to be 60% of that? Is the outer div the container for the whole page?

Comment: **Note** that the *percentage* value for the top/bottom `padding`/`margin` properties is relative to the `width` of the containing block.

Comment: I every now and then wonder if I'm doing things in the conventionally accepted manner. While I understand that when it comes to certain things there is no conventionally accepted manner, I do know that there is generally a bad set of practices, and was wondering if this was one of them is all. Itching a scratch.

Comment: I would like it to remain 60% from the top. The outer div is the page container, or wrapper. And thanks for the note, Hashem. I did not know that.

Comment: Well, it's better to remove the `.inner` from document normal flow by `position: absolute;` while the parent (`.outer`) has a `relative` position as a reference point for the absolute positioned elements. Then use `top: 60%;` for the `.inner` to position the element (from its top) to 60% of the height of the `.outer` box.

Comment: In addition, if you want to count the `60%` value from the top of the `.outer` to the middle of the `.inner`, you have 2 choice: Whether to specify an explicit `height` for the `.inner` and use a negative top `margin` as the half of the `height`, or to use CSS3 transform `translateY(-50%)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would stay away from positioning the element if it's not necessary, because it sometime leads to overlapping content and other issues.
Margins are the number of pixels around the element i.e outside the borders (background doesn't extend to margins), while padding is the number of pixels between the border and the content of the element.
So if you don't have any border or background specified, margins  and padding s do the same.
Please note that you would probably want to set percentage values to get the same result on different screens e.g 60%. EDIT: it will be relevant to the width of the containing element.

Comment: As I [noted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209187/vertically-positioning-elements#comment33719705_22209187), the percentage value for top padding/margin doesn't work as expected in this case.

Comment: Percentage value will depend on the parent height in case of margin/padding top, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Absolutely not. `The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.` - [CSS level 2 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties)

Comment: Well, that's new .. thanks Hashem .. I edited the answer